# Border appearing on focus of button

Tags: html, css

I have two buttons on my web page which look as follows...

[image: Image of buttons]

The button on the left has the correct style border; thin and with no rounded corners.

The button on the right, which currently has focus, does not have the correct style border. When Inspecting the element within chrome, it has the following properties...

```
element.style {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 25px;
    border: none !important;
    right: 140px;
}
.btn:focus {
    border-radius: 0px;
}
.btn-primary.focus, .btn-primary:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #286090;
}
.btn.focus, .btn:focus, .btn:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.btn.active.focus, .btn.active:focus, .btn.focus, .btn:active.focus, .btn:active:focus, .btn:focus {
    outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
    outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

I would have thought that applying the `border: none !important` css property (while the element was forced into a `focus` state would have worked, but apparently not.

Furthermore, even when I set the `border-color` to `yellow` while the button is focused, this effect is not applied.

How can I prevent the border from being rounded off, so that it stays square and the corners remain a 90 degree angle?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `outline`?

Comment: @yinsweet I'm perplexed as to how I missed that... Anyways, that's done the trick. Much appreciated!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see as an [outline](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp).

Just add this line to the button's css:

```
outline: none !important;
```

The purpose of the outline is accessabilty, so you should think carefully about removing it. You can always change the way the border looks instead.

As for `!important`, if you write your css right, you shouldn't use it. Inline css (`style='color: blue'`) supercedes classes and id styling, so in your case the `!important` might be redundant.

Comment: !immportant is a bad practice. Removing the outline is another bad practice

Comment: Removing outline isnt neccessaraly a bad practice. I will write about `!important`.

Comment: Inline CSS in Not necessary here. The best solution would be to create a rule with high specificity value

Answer (score 0):

There will be a lot of suggestions to remove the outline.
Before You decide to do so, please note that it'a a really bad practice from the accesibility point of view

https://medium.com/better-programming/a11y-never-remove-the-outlines-ee4efc7a9968